# C++03 vector as buffer class

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

It is very common situation:

```
int checkSomething() {
    char *buff = new char[SOMTHING_SIZE];
    int ret = 0;
    fillSomething(buff);
    /// Check data in buff and set ret value.
    ...
    ///
    delete [] buff;
    return ret;
}
```

I think it will be much more safe (for developer) to use vector:

```
int checkSomething() {
    std::vector<char> buff(SOMETHING_SIZE);
    int ret = 0;
    fillSomething(&buff[0]);
    /// Check data in buff and set ret value.
    ...
    ///
    return ret;
}
```

It prevents situation when you return from function before call delete.

Question: What is disadvantage of vector usage? I saw a lot of code with `new`/`delete` where it would be easy to use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use a `char* buff` and not a `char buff[BUFFER_SIZE]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is disadvantage of vector usage? I saw a lot of code with new/delete where would be easy to use vector.

There's actually no disadvantage to use `std::vector<char>` instead.

> I think it will be much more safe (for developer) to use vector.

You're correct. It's just designed as a replacement for doing this with raw array pointers, and at least any proper implementation according maintaining size and reallocations would need to do the same as the `std::vector` implementation already does (which could be hard avoiding all of the lurking pitfalls).

It's easy to get `new[]` `delete[]` wrong in custom implementations, but hard to fail with `std::vector` that's the reason why it existed from the very beginnings of C++ standard definitions.

---

With the current standard and assuming `SOMETHING_SIZE` is a constant value `std::array` should be even preferred, if the buffer should be statically allocated on the stack and would fit there.

Comment: `std::vector` is larger than a bare `T*`.  Usually not a *significant* disadvantage, but it is a disadvantage nevertheless.

Comment: @BenVoigt Totally depends if size needs to be managed at runtime or not. Not actually stated in the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The size is fairly obviously a constant.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, you have a valid point, at least using the current standard. But in the question title it explicitly states _C++03_.

Answer (score 2):

The difference here is that `std::vector` will free the memory its elements occupied, whereas you have to manually `delete` the dynamically allocated array, which you happen to be doing the wrong way - there should be `delete []` instead of `delete`, because it's an array you're deallocating.

Not to forgot the deallocation, in case your function early returns/throws an exception can be a pain. We've had RAII for that.

As a matter of fact, `std::array` will serve you just as well (with possibly smaller binary) if `SOMTHING_SIZE` is known at compile-time.

Comment: Yep, I did a misatake with delete without []. And I can not use std::array in C++03. Yes C++03 still in use.

Comment: @John That limitation escaped my mind somewhere on the road from the question to the answers' section.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it will be much more safe (for developer) to use vector.

You are correct.

> What is disadvantage of vector usage?

There isn't one.

> I saw a lot of code with new/delete where would be easy to use vector.

Yes, there is a lot of terrible code in the world.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out the intermediate solution, which acts much more like the original `new[]`...`delete[]` but is safe (doesn't require you to remember deallocation, doesn't leak in the presence of exceptions).

That is:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buff{new char[SOMETHING_SIZE]};
```

or

```
auto buff = std::make_unique<char[]>(SOMETHING_SIZE);
```

It has a size chosen at runtime (unlike `std::array`).

It does not allow resizing or copying.  If you want those, you should move up to `std::vector`.  But sometimes you don't want them, and `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` saves the extra overhead that `std::vector` needs in order to keep track of varying size.

Note that these are standardized in C++11 (and C++14, for `make_unique`), but can be built in C++03 also.

Comment: Thanks. But I was speaking about C++03 legacy code even without boost pointers. In this case vectors would be preferred solution.

Comment: @JohnGreen: Starting in C++11, `std::unique_ptr` makes good use of brand-new language features such as move constructors.  But even without those, you can write a smart pointer that's far far better than a raw pointer -- the only essential feature is RAII and that's been around since C++ was first standardized.